# Substituting Formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Substituting the formula for height of a tree in the formula for volume of a tree, the new formula for volume becomes ________________.

A)V = (1/3)πr(kr2/3)

B)V = (1/3)πr2

C)V = (1/3)πkr3

D)V = (1/3)πkr8/3

h = kr2/3 where k is a constant, h is the tree’s height, and r is the tree’s radius.
The formula for the volume of the tree is V = (1/3)πr2h.

Comment: You're given $\color{red}{h = kr^2/3}$ if I'm understanding your notation correctly. $$V= \frac 13\cdot \pi r^2(\color{red}{\text{put h here}})$$

Answer (score 0):

I believe your formatting is off.

I am pretty new to it as well but

Should $h=kr^{2/3}$
and $ V=(1/3 *pi* hr^{2})$

If so, then substituting in $h$ into $V$ gives

$V=((1/3)*pi*k*r^{2}*r^{2/3})$

Combining the exponents gives

$v=((1/3)*pi*k*r^{8/3})$

which is answer D)

Comment: Thank you! I will let you know if it's right. :)